# Cron Job vs. Scheduler: Understanding the Differences and Use Cases

Tags: cron, scheduling, jobs

What are the key differences between a Cron job and a scheduler, and in what use cases is using one of these tools more appropriate than using the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have here a list of schedulers: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software

Cron is one of them. A simple one. Some other may be more scalable or support dynamic programming of tasks, support dependancy, the presentation of a dashboard (which jobs was successful executed). There are plenty of characteristics which could differ from a scheduler to an other.

Note: it is hard to find information about cron type schedulers on Linux since "scheduler" also mean which process the kernel should allocate to the CPU at each milliseconds. I guess this is off topic here.